# Joomla popup overlay in home page

Tags: jquery, joomla, authentication, popup, overlay

I would like a jquery popup overlay on the home page.
if you are not logged in: the popup should only appear after a click anywhere on the page and must contain the login form and registration-

If you are logged in the popup does not appear.

How can I do this?

Comment: What version of Joomla! are you using? This is going to require both PHP and JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 

   $session = JFactory::getSession();
   $isUserLogged = $session->get('YOUR_SESSION_VARIABLE');

   if(empty($isUserLogged )):
?>
      <script type='text/javascript'>
         $(document).ready(function(){
            //OPEN LOGIN MODAL AND SET THE SESSION COOKIE
         });
      </script>
 <?php
  endif;
 ?>
```

Hope it works :)